# I can not open my divs gracefully

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some script that I could really use some help on. Everything works great as is but I would like the `div` to open gracefully instead of instantly. I have the default for all of them closed and need to keep them that way. In addition, I only want 1 div opened, so the other must close when 1 is clicked.  I have tried `fadein` and `toggle` without success. Can anyone help me with this please?

https://jsfiddle.net/lepew/xh5x4cgc/3/

```js
function toggle(id)
{
   var e = document.getElementById(id);

   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none'; 
   else
      var list = document.getElementsByClassName("dbn");
      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
      {
         list[i].style.display="none";
         e.style.display = 'block';
      }
}
```

```css
.dbn
{
   display: none;
   xfloat: right;
   xfloat: left;
   xwidth: 30%;
   xborder: .05em solid #000;
   border: 1px solid lime;
   padding: .8em;
   margin: 1em;
   box-shadow: 0 0 .3em #000;

}
#aa
{
   background-color:#f00;
   xfloat: left;
}

#bb
{
   background-color:#0f0;
   xfloat: left;
}

#cc
{   
   background-color:#00f;
   xfloat: left;
}

#pepe
{
border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.lepew
{
width: 150px;
display: inline-block;
background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
    <div id="pepe">
        <a onclick="toggle('aa');" class="lepew" style="cursor:pointer ">Peter</a>
        <a onclick="toggle('bb');" class="lepew" style="cursor:pointer ">Paul</a>
        <a onclick="toggle('cc');" class="lepew" style="cursor:pointer ">Mary</a>
    </div>
    <div id="aa" class="dbn">
        Content of Div aa
    </div>
    <div id="bb" class="dbn">
        Content of Div bb
    </div>
    <div id="cc" class="dbn">
        Content of Div cc
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
<div>
Nuthing here
</div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
```

Comment: why didn't  use  `fadeIn` `FadeOut` instead handle it by css?

Comment: I am trying to avoid a lot of additional code IF it is possible to add 1 or 2 lines in the script somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this page : http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/.

> As of jQuery 1.6, the [`.promise()`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) method can be used in conjunction with the [`deferred.done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) method to execute a single callback for the animation as a whole when all matching elements have completed their animations ( See the [example for .promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/#example-1) ).

```js
$("button").on("click", function () {
  var button = $(this);
  var parent = button.parent();
  var buttons = parent.children();
  var i = buttons.index(button);
  var panels = $("#panels").children();
  panels.finish(); // stop running animation
  panels.slideUp().promise().done(function () {
    $("#panels").children().eq(i).slideDown();
  });
});
```

```css
#buttons { margin-bottom: .5em; }
#panels > div { padding: .5em; }
#panels > div { display: none; }
#panel-1 { background: #c5e1a5; }
#panel-2 { background: #fff59d; }
#panel-3 { background: #b2dfdb; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttons">
  <button type="button">panel #1</button>
  <button type="button">panel #2</button>
  <button type="button">panel #3</button>
</div>
<div id="panels">
  <div id="panel-1">panel #1</div>
  <div id="panel-2">panel #2</div>
  <div id="panel-3">panel #3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, except 1 of the divs is open.  Can I default to have them closed and only open when clicked?

Comment: @user3344341 Sure : `#panels > div { display: none; }`. Answer updated :-)

Comment: @user3344341 Further reading : http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/.

Answer (score 0):

How about no `javascript` or `jquery` solution using `CSS` only, use `:focus` to detect click and animate the div height using `keyframes`

```css
.my-menu {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #6D565E;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
}

.my-menu a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.my-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #F4D7CB;
}

.my-menu a span {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: pink;
  text-align: center;
  height: 0px;
  width: 600px;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0;
  color: #6D565E;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.my-menu a:focus span {
  -webkit-animation-name: slidedown;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-name: slidedown;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidedown {
  0% {
    height: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 600px;
  }
}


/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes slidedown {
  0% {
    height: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 600px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-menu">
  <a class="lepew" href="#.">Peter<span>
  Content of Div aa
</span>
</a>

  <a class="lepew" href="#.">Paul<span>
  Content of Div bb
</span></a>
  <a class="lepew" href="#.">Mary<span>
  Content of Div cc
</span></a>
</div>



<br />
<br />
<div>
  Nuthing here
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
```